# Core Data Model Subclassing (Not NSManagedObject subclassing)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I would like to know if anyone knows if it is possible to subclass a Core Data Model.

In my case I am developing a library that I would like to use in 2 projects. Both projects have nearly the same Data Objects that i would like to outsource into the library, because there are some classes and methods in this library which requires to know about the existence of these Entities.

Some ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more stable through future releases to add a Category on NSManagedObjectModel, instead of subclassing it.

Comment: Of course I use categories, but that ist not the solution for my question. I want to extend the core data object graph, not an entity or NSManagedObjectModel